# conditionals, ruby. TicTacToe

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am currently trying to implement a tic tac toe console-version. I have a set of specs to guide me through the methods I need to write and such. Currently, I am working on my "winner" method that determines whether :X or :O has won the game. I know my implementation this far is VERY expensive since I am using a lot of loops to check for each possibility. I will try to refactor that after I completely have my function working. I am struggling when to make my function return "nil" at the end if none of the conditions is met and I don't happen to find the reason for it!!Can anyone spot my mistake? Here is my code:

```
    class Board

  attr_reader :grid, :marks

  def self.grid
    (Array.new(3) { Array.new(3) })
  end

  def initialize(grid = Board.grid)
    @grid = grid
    @marks = [:X, :O]
  end

  def [](pos)
    row, col = pos
    @grid[row][col]
  end

  def []=(pos, value)
    row, col = pos
    @grid[row][col] = value
  end

  def empty?(pos)
    self[pos].nil?
  end

  def place_mark(pos, mark)
    self[pos] = mark
  end

  def winner
    @grid.each do |row|
      return :X if row.each.all? { |mark| mark == :X }
    end
    @grid.transpose.each do |col|
      return :X if col.each.all? { |mark| mark == :X }
    end
    @grid.each do |row|
      return :O if row.each.all? { |mark| mark == :O }
    end
    @grid.transpose.each do |col|
      return :O if col.each.all? { |mark| mark == :O }
    end
    if @grid[0, 0] = :X && @grid[1, 1] = :X && @grid[2, 2] = :X &&
       @grid[2, 2] = :X
      return :X
    elsif @grid[0, 0] = :O && @grid[1, 1] = :O && @grid[2, 2] = :O &&
       @grid[2, 2] = :O
      return :O
    end
    nil   # HERE! I can't make this run! :/ 
  end

  def over?
    @grid.flatten.none?{|sqr| sqr.nil?} || self.winner != :X
    return true if self.winner == :X
  end
end
```

And this are my specs for that function

```
describe "winner" do
    context "when :X has won" do
      context "on a row" do
        it "returns :X" do
          place_marks([[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2]], :X)

          expect(board.winner).to be :X
        end
      end

      context "on the left diagonal" do
        it "returns :X" do
          place_marks([[0, 0], [1, 1], [2, 2]], :X)

          expect(board.winner).to be :X
        end
      end

      context "on the right diagonal" do
        it "returns :X" do
          place_marks([[0, 2], [1, 1], [2, 0]], :X)

          expect(board.winner).to be :X
        end
      end
    end

    context "when :O has won a column" do
      it "returns :O" do
        place_marks([[0, 2], [1, 2], [2, 2]], :O)

        expect(board.winner).to be :O
      end
    end

    context "when there is no winner" do
      it "returns nil" do
        expect(board.winner).to be nil

        fill_cats_game

        expect(board.winner).to be nil
      end
    end
  end
```

I know it might be a dumb mistake but, I really want to have clear where I am wrong for future code. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, as per provided explanation by @Simple Lime, you should use conditional statement as below in `winner` method and also `nested array` should be accessed as below:

```
if @grid[0][0] == :X && @grid[1][1] == :X && @grid[2][2] == :X
  return :X
elsif @grid[0][0] == :O && @grid[1][1] == :O && @grid[2][2] == :O
  return :O
end
```

Your method will look like as below:

```
  def winner
    @grid.each do |row|
      return :X if row.each.all? { |mark| mark == :X }
    end
    @grid.transpose.each do |col|
      return :X if col.each.all? { |mark| mark == :X }
    end
    @grid.each do |row|
      return :O if row.each.all? { |mark| mark == :O }
    end
    @grid.transpose.each do |col|
      return :O if col.each.all? { |mark| mark == :O }
    end
    if @grid[0][0] == :X && @grid[1][1] == :X && @grid[2][2] == :X
      return :X
    elsif @grid[0][0] == :O && @grid[1][1] == :O && @grid[2][2] == :O
      return :O
    end
  end
```

x_board = Board.new([[:O, :X, :X], [:O, :X, :O], [:O, :X, :X]])

```
x_board.winner
=> :X
```

o_board = Board.new([[:O, :X, :X], [:O, :O, :X], [:X, :O, :O]])

```
o_board.winner
=> :O
```

nil_board = Board.new

```
nil_board.winner
=> nil
```

Comment: OMG! yes. My eyes totally ignored that. Thank you so much! @Rhunal